# Qt - webkit - how to extract images out of a web page

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, webkit

I am trying to extract the images from the given web page. I have gone through "Simple Selector Example" and "DOM Traversal Example" .  But, they refer text-things not image. I have made a code to get a QNetWorkReply by sending QNetworkRequest through QNetworkManager. But, I can't get how to bring images using it. Qt-Webkit enlightened ones are asked to shed a light on  this.

Comment: I guess you must select images then. Do you know basic HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QWebElement](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qwebelement.html) has tagName and attributeNames, you want to search for an `img` tag with a `src` attribute.

You can download URLs with [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-download-main-cpp.html).

Comment: I checked your solution. But, QWebFrame class can give the elements which are filtered by the selector "CSS2 selector".  The function is "QWebFrame::findAllElements ( const QString & selectorQuery ) const" . But, this standard "CSS2" has only attributes related things, not tag related things. Can you say the way to find the elements as you said

Comment: CSS attributes are not like HTML attributes. `<img src="foo.png" />` img is a HTML attribute.

Comment: I used "*" which gave me what I wanted. Now I am having the elements which are having images. But, can you say how to extract the image out of these QWebElement's.

Comment: Well now you have the URL you can fetch it directly. Webkit may already have downloaded and cached it -- I don't know -- but Qt has *excellent* documentation. Happy digging.

Comment: Hi, now I got our point clearly. I got the image's web address by the attribute "src". Still, I don't know how to get the image out of this web address. The address is something like this "http://**/pic12.jpg" .